# How can I fix "cannot find a valid baseurl for repo" errors on CentOS?

Tags: centos

I finished installing CentOS 6, but when I tried running `yum update` I got:

```
[root@centos6test ~]# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit
Determining fastest mirrors
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=i386&repo=os
error was 14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "" Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

Why is that happening? How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you connected to the network? Can you ping mirrorlist.centos.org?

Comment: What happens if you run `curl 'http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=i386&repo=os'` ?

Answer (score 171, accepted):

First you need to get connected, AFAIK CentOS 6 minimal set your network device to `ONBOOT=No`, just do a `dhclient` with admin privileges to your network interface and you should be up and running:

`$ sudo dhclient`

Comment: I used to setup dhcp client on my remote server using ssh according to this answer and now I lost the connection because server IP is dynamically changed now and I was not thinking of that case before applying changes. This answer is fallacious without enough description and leads to misunderstandings.

Comment: For CentOS-7 (1611) version, the `ONBOOT=No` is located in a file like `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3`.  I edited that file to `ONBOOT=yes` and reboot can fix it.

Comment: Changing to `ONBOOT=yes` in `/etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-enp0s3` works for me, thanks @JohnnyWong

Answer (score 25):

I had been struggling with the same problem on **Centos6.4** x86_64. I got the following error
:

```
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was 14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'" Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

So, I fixed it by these steps:

edit network interface. For my case, I used `eth0` in CentOS 6.X
In CentOS 7 you can use the "ensxxx" interface.

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

update **NM_CONTROLLED** to **no**

```
ONBOOT=no
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=8.8.4.4
```

restart the network interface

```
ifdown eth0
ifup eth0
```

Comment: `ifcfg-eth0` does not exist on CentOs 7

Comment: @shailenTJ Just touch it ~ works fine.

Comment: @shailenTJ They changed the naming system, it'll be enpXsX, on my system it's enp0s3, but it will probably be slighty different on yours.

Comment: If you do "minimal install", its "ifcfg-enpls0f0". But if you install with a GUI, it overrides that file with something else. Then you use the network settings tool at the top right corner of the main desktop screen.

Comment: `4.2.2.2` probably isn't the DNS entry you want!

Comment: Fixed, people is copy/pasting from here, better be precise.

Answer (score 15):

I had the same issue and it got resolved after I edited `/etc/yum.conf` file. If you are running on proxy server and the IP which is given to the server is bypassed but still when you open in browser (IE - we need to give check mark on proxy but no need to give username and password.)

Add this following line in the main section of the file /etc/yum.conf file.

```
proxy=http://xxx.xxx.xx.xx:8080
```

ie, substituting the proxy address with actual proxy. Also change the port number if it is not 8080.

If proxy requires authentication, add this also to the file

```
proxy_username=username
proxy_password=password
```

Answer (score 13):

I edited the file `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` and uncommented `baseurl`:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

Comment: Thanks! This worked for me. Does anyone know why this is needed, or why it was commented out if it is needed?

Answer (score 9):

If pinging a well known host by its name (e.g. `ping www.google.com`) returns `ping: unknown host` but pinging an ip (e.g. `ping 8.8.8.8`) works fine then you have a DNS resolution issue -- try adding these entries to `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
nameserver 8.8.8.8
nameserver 8.8.4.4
```

Answer (score 5):

Happened to me on CentOS 6 as it has reached end-of-life due to which no mirrors work now. Though you can use Vault repo where everything has been moved.

For **CentOS 6**, do:

```
curl https://www.getpagespeed.com/files/centos6-eol.repo --output /etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo
```

or take a look [here](https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/how-to-fix-yum-after-centos-6-went-eol).
This should fix up yum.

Comment: Be careful with this, as that file is specifically for v.6.10...

Comment: https://www.getpagespeed.com/server-setup/how-to-fix-yum-after-centos-6-went-eol

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem yesterday and I spent hours trying to solve it. The solution ended up being simple.

Delete the contents of `/etc/yum.repos.d/remi.repo` and then execute

```
# yum update
```

It's done! The file's content will start the download again and be configured.

Comment: Where is this `remi.repo` file located?

Comment: /etc/yum.repos.d/

Comment: I may have miss something, but where do you see he has the Remi's repo installed ? He clearly mentioned 'I finished installing CentOS6', I kind of doubt Remi's repo are configured. I might be wrong...

Comment: The issue is a malformed file under `/etc/yum.repos.d` - `remi.repo` just happened to be the filename in this case

Answer (score 1):

Here's yet another possibility that I stumbled upon, causing this problem:

I was using a Puppet module to create the EPEL repo for CentOS, the stahnma/epel module.

Within the module it constructed the repo URL with the variable `::os_maj_version` which didn't exist in my list of facts. I had to replace that with ::operatingsystemmajrelease.

So the URL in `/etc/yum.repos.d/epel.repo` was malformed.

Answer (score 0):

All previous answers are correct but unfortunately did not work for me.
The below command worked for me:

**Warning this will delete all of you Centos repos !!!
       use this at your own risk**

```
mkdir ~/backup
cp -r /etc/yum.repos.d/Cen* ~/backup
rm /etc/yum.repos.d/Cen*
```

Comment: this will delete repo from system

Comment: You should probably consider including the procedure to recreate the deleted repository files once you have deleted them all.

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me on a Centos 7 environment, and I was able to solve it with the following command:

```
yum clean all
```

I had not run any yum command for a few months, seems like the cached metadata got obsolete.

Answer (score 0):

My user's problem was simpler. He needed an extra repo added, so I copied my entry to him in a chat window. He added it to the repo file and got the error in the subject. After some playing around I deleted the new entry, copied and pasted an existing entry from within his own file and then edited the changes to reflect the added repo. It worked fine.

So the problem was some sort of formatting error caused by the way he copied and pasted the content into the file.

Answer (score -1):

I had a slightly different error on our CentOS 7. I followed one of the suggestions and fixed it.

The error is:

```
$ sudo yum update mesa-libgbm

...

Could not retrieve mirrorlist https://mirrors.iuscommunity.org/mirrorlist?repo=ius-centos7&arch=x86_64&protocol=http error was
14: curl#6 - "Could not resolve host: mirrors.iuscommunity.org; Name or service not known"

 One of the configured repositories failed (Unknown),
 and yum doesn't have enough cached data to continue. At this point the only
 safe thing yum can do is fail. There are a few ways to work "fix" this:

...

     3. Run the command with the repository temporarily disabled
            yum --disablerepo=<repoid> ...

...

Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: ius/x86_64
```

I tried again using the 3rd suggestion and it worked.