# Update yum fails

Tags: linux, yum, upgrade, centos

I'm using centOS 6.4.

I'm getting this error when I use "yum update" in the terminal window.

```
 Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was
14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'"
Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

Is there any alternative mirror for Upgrading?

Comment: Can you ping mirrorlist.centos.org? If not you have DNS problem.. Try to add 8.8.8.8 DNS server.

Comment: or the less spying openDNS adress to your DNS: 208.67.222.222 ,
208.67.220.220.
what happen if you ping of this what is the content of the file resolv.conf ?

Comment: Just in case, add you `ifconfig` and `route` output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had been struggling with the same problem on Centos6.4 x86_64. I got the following error 
:

```
Could not retrieve mirrorlist http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=6&arch=x86_64&repo=os error was 14: PYCURL ERROR 6 - "Couldn't resolve host 'mirrorlist.centos.org'" Error: Cannot find a valid baseurl for repo: base
```

So, I fixed it by these steps:

edit network interface. For my case, I used `eth0`.

```
vim /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
```

update **NM_CONTROLLED** to **no**

```
ONBOOT=no
NM_CONTROLLED=no
BOOTPROTO=dhcp
DNS1=8.8.8.8
DNS2=4.2.2.2
```

restart the network interface

```
ifdown eth0
ifup eth0
```

I posted the same answer at : [How can I fix "cannot find a valid baseurl for repo" errors on CentOS?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/22924/how-can-i-fix-cannot-find-a-valid-baseurl-for-repo-errors-on-centos/)