# cannot find a valid baseURL for repo : pgdg94

Tags: bash, centos, root, postgresql, sme-server

bonjour j'ai un soucis pour l'installation de postgresql dans mon serveur sme 9.2 a chaque fois que j'essaie de l'installer avec la commande yum install on m'affiche un message d'erreur "error:cannot find a vaid baseURL for repo : pgdg94" ca fait plus d'une sémaine que j'arrive pas à avancer dans mon travail  à cause de ca. s'il vous plait j'ai besoin de votre aide. merci d'avance

Google translated:

hello i have a problem installing postgresql in my server sme 9.2 every time i try to install it with the yum install command I get an error message "error: can not find a vaid baseURL for repo: pgdg94 "It's been more than a seminary that I can not get ahead in my work because of that. please I need your help. thank you in advance

Comment: En anglais, s'il vous plait.

Comment: This seems to be [a common problem](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/22924/3645): You need to be online.